# AngularJs - work with service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services

I am very new to Angular. I have watched some tutorials and read some of the documentation and I start coding.

this is my code:

```
angular.module('CourseStoryApp').service("CourseStoryService", ['$http', '$routeParams', function ($http, $routeParams) {
    return $http({
        url: "CourseStoryWebService.asmx/Course",
        method: "GET",
        params: { eID: $routeParams.eid }
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}]);

angular.module('CourseStoryApp').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'CourseStoryService', function ($scope, CourseStoryService) {
   CourseStoryService.then(function (data) {
     $scope.courseStory = data;  
   });
}]);
```

is this the correct way to create a service and call it on controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Service should contain some methods which are in the context of `CourseStories`. You may want to `get` a specific Item, `delete` one and stuff like this. It would be silly to create seperate services for each of these use cases.

To create methods which are `publicly` available, assign them to the `this` variable inside the service.

So your Service could look like this:

```
angular
  .module('CourseStoryApp')
  .service('CourseStoryService', ['$http', function($http) {

    // Better to uncouple the service from the router, so you have a generic
    // 'getStory' method.
    this.getStory = function(id) {
      return $http({
        url: "CourseStoryWebService.asmx/Course",
        method: "GET",
        params: { eID: id }
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      }, function() {
        // Error handling
        // Maybe write some logs etc.
      });
    };
  }]);
```

And your Controller could use this Service like this:

```
angular
  .module('CourseStoryApp')
  .controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'CourseStoryService', function($scope, $routeParams, CourseStoryService) {

    // Consume your Service Method like this.
    CourseStoryService.getStory($routeParams.eid).then(function(data) {
      $scope.courseStory = data;
    }, function() {
      // Error Handler
      // Notify user etc.
    });
  }]);
```

Note that the `$http` provider from angular has some shortcut methods for specific request types like `$http.get()` etc. You can read more in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .then() method, you have to implement something called promise in your service.

If you're new to angular, I really suggest you to learn about Angular 2 or more. The first version encountered some problems

Comment: can give me an example how to implement the promise in my service?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. $HTPP already return a promise. You should remove .then() method in your service and only call the .then() method outside the service